# laravel 5.2 image could not load

Tags: php, laravel

hello i am trying to learn laravel and when i was watching this course a lecture came up about image uploading and displaying i did the uploading part without a problem and created the tables and relations but when i was trying to display the image it would not load the images are inside a folder by the name of 'images' in the public folder

this is the display table

```php
 @if($users)

        @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
                <td><img height="50" src="/images/{{$user->photo ? $user->photo->file : 'no photo'}}" alt=""></td>
                <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->role->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->is_active == 1 ? 'Active' : 'Not Active'}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->updated_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
            </tr>

    @endforeach
        @endif
```

this is my controller

```php
public function store(UsersRequest $request)
    {
        //        User::create($request->all());

        $input = $request->all();

        if($file = $request->file('photo_id')){

            $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('images' , $name);
            $photo = Photo::create(['file' => $name]);
            $input['photo_id'] = $photo->id;
        }

        $input['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
        User::create($input);

        return redirect('/admin/users');

        //        return $request->all();
    }
```

this is my model i did this so that the file name display can be dynamic instead of writing /image/ in the image src but still didnt work

```php
class Photo extends Model
{
    //


    protected $uploads = '/images/';

    protected $fillable = ['file'];

    public function getFileAttribute($photo){

        return $this->uploads.$photo;

    }


}
```

Comment: What does the HTML output look like?  I'd verify the HTML looks valid and the URL it's outputting in the src attribute is correct.

Comment: its all correct when i return the image path its totally correct

Comment: So you can visit the path in the src attribute and it loads an image?

Comment: no it does not load the image thats my problem but i can echo out the name of the image and insdie the images folder that image name exists

Comment: So it does have /images/imagename in the HTML src attribute (from inspecting in your browser).  The issue isn't really with your code then, it's most likely your web server setup and you'll have to provide more details.  Is the public folder your web root directory?

Comment: {{  asset('storage/images/.$user->photo) }}

Comment: Devon yes it is

Answer (score 0):

replace index.blade.php with the below :

```
 @if($users)

        @foreach($users as $user)



      <tr>
        <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
         <td><img height='50' src='{{$user->photo?$user->photo->file:"No image"}}'></td>

        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->role->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->is_active==1?'Active':'Not Active'}}</td>

        <td>{{$user->created_at->diffForhumans()}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->updated_at->diffForhumans()}}</td>
      </tr>

      @endforeach

    @endif
```

Photo.php is here :

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Photo extends Model
{


protected $fillable=['file'];
    protected $uploads='../images/';

public function getFileAttribute($photo)
{

    return $this->uploads . $photo;
}

}
```

the controller is here:

```
  public function store(UsersRequest $request)
    {

        $input=$request->all();

        if($file=$request->file('photo_id')){  //check if the user has submit photo from the form
           $name=time().$file->getClientOriginalName(); //append the time in the beginning to make image unique
           $file->move('images',$name); //move the image to the image folder in public dir
           $photo=photo::create(['file'=>$name]); //inserting the image in the photo table , file column
           $input['photo_id']=$photo->id; //getting its ID of the inserted record and storing it in the input array

        }
       $input['password']=bcrypt($request->password);// encrypting the password from the request variable , and storing it in the input array
        user::create($input); //inserting all the input array in the user's table which means photo_id as well above

        return redirect('/admin/users'); //returing the user to the display users

    }
```

Comment: Some explanation of what you have changed and how this solves the problem would help improve the answer.